page limit in Reading Settings wordpress
currentlly, i have 100k page url in my website wordpress.
So, i not access in reading setting. because it have error "Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 268435456 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 20480 bytes) in /www/wwwroot/beetrust.click/wp-includes/class-wpdb.php on line 2320 There has been a critical error on this website. Please check your site admin email inbox for instructions"
I want page limit show in "reading setting".
So i can access in "reading setting".
i added code follow in my function.php but it not work.
add_action('load-options-reading.php', 'limit_reading_settings_dropdown');
function limit_reading_settings_dropdown() {
add_filter('wp_dropdown_pages', 'custom_wp_dropdown_pages', 10, 2);
}
function custom_wp_dropdown_pages($output, $args)
{
    if (isset($args['name']) && ($args['name'] === 'page_on_front' || $args['name'] === 'page_for_posts')) {
        $pages = get_pages(
            array(
                'number' => 10,
                'sort_column' => 'post_title',
'sort_order' => 'ASC'
            )
        );

        $output = '<select name="' . esc_attr($args['name']) . '" id="' . esc_attr($args['id']) . '">' . "\n";
        $output .= '<option value="0">' . esc_html($args['show_option_none']) . '</option>' . "\n";

        foreach ($pages as $page) {
            $selected = selected($args['selected'], $page->ID, false);
            $output .= '<option class="level-0" value="' . esc_attr($page->ID) . '"' . $selected . '>' . esc_html($page->post_title) . '</option>' . "\n";
        }

        $output .= '</select>' . "\n";
    }

    return $output;
}


add_action('load-options-reading.php' - what kind of hook is that supposed to be? A hook / filter name containing a PHP script filename would be highly unusual.
